# How fix error: Specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm?

Tags: c#, aes, .net-6.0

My encription code:

```
    private string GetHash(HMAC hash, string input)
    {
        byte[] data = hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            builder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }

    private byte[] GetVector()
    {
        var hash = GetHash(HMACSHA256.Create("HmacSHA256"), "<some_key>");

        using var aes = Aes.Create();
        aes.Key = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(hash); // exception. keySize = 64 bytes
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        aes.GenerateIV();
        return aes.IV.Concat(aes.IV).ToArray();
    }
```

I do not know how change keySize. I think it`s need 32 bytes.

Perhaps I need to change the encryption method?

Any help. I'm new to encryption. Thanks

Comment: Why are you returning the hash as a string, when you actually want it as bytes anyway? You're basically breaking it at the moment by encoding the hash as hex, then "decoding" it using `Encoding.Default.GetBytes(hash)`. (Aside from anything else, `Encoding.Default` is *almost always* the wrong encoding to use.) I suggest you just change `GetHash` to return `data` directly - skip the encoding/decoding.

Comment: Your example makes little sense to me. What are you really trying to do? If you want to use a password for encryption you should take a look at [key derivation algorithms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.cryptography.core.keyderivationalgorithmprovider?view=winrt-22621). If you want to pass the key between systems you would typically use base64 encoding.

Comment: In your code, the actual encryption seems to be missing. Usually IV and ciphertext are concatenated. However, concatenating the IV with itself (`aes.IV.Concat(aes.IV)`) does not make much sense.

Comment: @JonSkeet, thanks. byte[] data = hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input)); - this works. I change old version this code with MD5 to SHA256 and this code `hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));` had 16 byte

Comment: Well yes, different hashes are different sizes... I'm not sure what you're trying to say here, but fundamentally it doesn't change the mistake in the code you presented